# python turtle if error

Tags: python, if-statement, turtle-graphics

I wanna make python snake game by using turtles and make levels. So, I checked score to decide user's level But, when the programs run [if statements], the movement of the turtle I already made gonna be slow. I don't know the reason of this error and How to figure out. I need your help ;(

```
def level():
global speed
if 0 <= score < 5:
    mypen.penup()
    mypen.hideturtle()
    mypen.setposition(-290, 310)
    levelstring = "level: 1"
    mypen.write(levelstring, False, align="left", font=('Consolas', 15, 'bold'))
    speed += 1
if 5 <= score < 10:
    mypen.penup()
    mypen.hideturtle()
    mypen.setposition(-290, 310)
    levelstring = "level: 2"
    mypen.write(levelstring, False, align="left", font=('Consolas', 15, 'bold'))
    speed += 2
elif 10 <= score:
    exit()
```

---

```
while True:
alex.forward(speed)

#boundary checking
if alex.xcor() > 300 or alex.xcor() < -300:
    alex.right(180)

if alex.ycor() > 300 or alex.ycor() < -300:
    alex.right(180)

# boundary checking
if ts.xcor() > 300 or ts.xcor() < -300:
    ts.right(180)

if ts.ycor() > 300 or ts.ycor() < -300:
    ts.right(180)

#collision.checking
d = math.sqrt(math.pow(alex.xcor()-ts.xcor(),2) + math.pow(alex.ycor()-ts.ycor(),2))
if d < 20:
    ts.setposition(random.randint(-300, 300), random.randint(-300, 300))
    score += 1
    level()

#Draw the score
mypen.penup()
mypen.hideturtle()
mypen.setposition(250,310)
scorestring = "Score: %s" %score
mypen.write(scorestring, False, align= "left", font=('Consolas', 15, 'bold'))
```

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include 
the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code  necessary 
to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without a **clear problem 
statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and 
Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: The code you posted isn't runnable and therefore it also isn't debuggable.

Comment: Post the error.

Comment: if you mess with the turtles.. you get the Trackeback venom telling you something is toxic. Fix code! And start using an editor (e.g. IDLE, IPyton or komodo edit)!

Comment: Sorry, this is my firt time to post my code, and the whole code too long to post. So, I didn't know how to show my error code

Answer (score 0):

The following is a working example I expanded from the code you provided.  It speeds up the automaton with each score and increasingly with each "level".  See if it behaves the way you desire:

```
from turtle import Turtle, Screen
from random import randint

FONT = ('Consolas', 15, 'bold')

def check_level():
    global speed, level

    score_pen.undo()
    score_pen.write("Score: %s" % score, False, align='right', font=FONT)

    if 0 <= score < 5:
        speed += 1
        level = 1
    elif 5 <= score < 10:
        speed += 3
        level = 2
        alex.speed('fastest')
    elif score >= 10:
        screen.bye()

    level_pen.undo()
    level_pen.write("Level: %s" % level, False, align='left', font=FONT)

def move_alex():
    global score

    alex.forward(speed)

    #boundary checking
    if alex.xcor() > 300 or alex.xcor() < -300:
        alex.right(180)

    if alex.ycor() > 300 or alex.ycor() < -300:
        alex.right(180)

    # boundary checking
    if ts.xcor() > 300 or ts.xcor() < -300:
        ts.right(180)

    if ts.ycor() > 300 or ts.ycor() < -300:
        ts.right(180)

    # collision.checking
    if ts.distance(alex) < 20:
        score += 1
        check_level()

        alex.hideturtle()
        alex.setposition(randint(-300, 300), randint(-300, 300))
        alex.showturtle()

    screen.ontimer(move_alex, 100)

def move_right():
    screen.onkey(None, 'Right')
    ts.right(45)
    screen.onkey(move_right, 'Right')

def move_left():
    screen.onkey(None, 'Left')
    ts.left(45)
    screen.onkey(move_left, 'Left')

def move_forward():
    screen.onkey(None, 'Up')
    ts.forward(speed * 1.25)
    screen.onkey(move_forward, 'Up')

screen = Screen()
screen.setup(660, 660)

score = 0
level = 1
speed = 5

# Draw the score
score_pen = Turtle(visible=False)
score_pen.penup()
score_pen.setposition(290, 310)
score_pen.write("Score: %s" % score, False, align='right', font=FONT)

level_pen = Turtle(visible=False)
level_pen.penup()
level_pen.setposition(-290, 310)
level_pen.write("Level: %s" % level, False, align='left', font=FONT)

alex = Turtle('square', visible=False)
alex.speed('normal')
alex.penup()
alex.setheading(45)
alex.setposition(randint(-300, 300), randint(-300, 300))
alex.showturtle()

ts = Turtle('turtle')
ts.speed('fastest')
ts.penup()

screen.onkey(move_right, 'Right')
screen.onkey(move_left, 'Left')
screen.onkey(move_forward, 'Up')

move_alex()
screen.listen()
screen.mainloop()
```

This is just an example of a barely playable game -- it clearly needs work to finish it and make it snake-like.